# Android: NFC intents in library that main project depends on

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development...

I have an application which uses a library to upload data to a website.  I want to make additions to the application to be able to read NFC tags.

I started out creating a small, separate application to get the hang of NFC. That app works fine.  Now, I need to bring in some of that code into this other application which depends on the aforementioned library.

The problem is, UNLESS I add an application node to the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the LIBRARY specifying the NFC intents, the intents do not fire.

[Snippet from library manifest mentioned above]

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="My App..."
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[The main application contains this application node in its manifest]

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.microsoft.azure.storage.samples.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Now comes the problem.... when a tag is detected, android tries to launch the activity from the library manifest file.  Since that activity doesn't exist, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.  I tried specifying `MainActivity` class from the application for the android:name of the application node in the LIBRARY manifest, but:

1. I can't compile the code.
2. It would be extremely poor practice even if that worked...

How do I get the NFC intents to fire without having to add intent-filter nodes in the library manifest?

Thank you!